# Cocos2d animations across multiple objects

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a tile object which I look through to see if I need to create an animation. If I need to I create the animation and add it to an array

I then go off and loop through some more tile objects adding more animation to the array.

I then want to run the array of animation in sequence however I don't have the original object to instantiate run action from, this means they have to be run on the last object which means they all start from that last objects position instead of the position that the animation was created from.

Can anyone suggest a way that I can build up an array of animations for multiple different objects then run it so they appear in the position on the board where I created them at.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by having a function i call in a loop after the animation has completed, not as clean as i hoped but a suitable solution.